# Efficiently adding or removing elements to a vector or list in R?

Tags: r, vector, performance

I'm implementing an algorithm that involves lots of adding and removing things from sets. In R, this is slow because as far as I know, adding or removing things from a vector is slow, since the entire vector has to be re-allocated. Is there a way do do it more efficiently?

Edit: My current solution is to use a boolean vector of the same length as the list of things that can be in the set, and using that as a membership table.

Comment: Is there any chance that you provide exact code? From you question I can't find out if you are using list or vectors, how you add or remove (what function?) elements, how works your current solution (is recreating logical vector instead add/remove to original?)? More information you provide, more optimization can be done.

Comment: new version of R should be better at this. Is that true?

Comment: I doubt that resizing a vector repeatedly as elements are added or removed from it will ever be fast.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chapter 2 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) has some interesting comments on this, including perdiodic growing objects to reduce memory fragmentation and allocation overhead.

If you know what the ultimate size of the set is, then the method you suggest is probably the best - ie `subset` from the whole universe using an approprate membership vector. Difficult to know whats best without seeing exactly what you are trying to do though.

Comment: I ended up with a boolean vector representing set membership.

Answer (score 15):

If you can, initializing a vector so that it has length equal to its maximum length during the algorithm may help.

e.g.

```
vec <- rep(NA,10)
vec[1:3] <- 1:3
vec[4:5] <- 4:5
vec[6:10] <- 6:10
```

rather than

```
vec <- 1:3
vec <- c(vec,4:5)
vec <- c(vec,6:10)
```

compare

```
> system.time({vec <- rep(NA,10^4); for (i in 1:(10^4)) vec[i] <- i })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.043   0.001   0.044
```

to

```
> system.time({vec <- NULL; for (i in 1:(10^4)) vec <- c(vec,i) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.249   0.089   0.335
```

Comment: But I could possibly be removing any item in the vector, not just the last.

Comment: Sure. The loops are just examples to show the difference between initializing a vector and building one with repeated assignment. I obviously haven't seen your algorithm but this method should still work though, as 'i' could be any number at any point in your algorithm. It only relies on knowing the length of your vector to begin with. Also, instead of removing it you'd just assign that element as 'NA' and maintain a vector of the same length.

Comment: You don't need to use `eval/parse`, it's enough when you take expression in braces, i.e.: `system.time({vec <- rep(NA,10^4);for (i in 1:(10^4)) vec[i] <- i})`

Comment: For info `append` is slower than `vec[i] <- i`

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to say what you want.  Maybe you really want stack commands like push and pop.  The following isn't that.  But it's a fast solution.

Allocate a vector large enough to hold all of your items of the type you need.  Set every value to NA.  Adding items is simple.  Removing items is setting them to NA again.  Using the vector is just `na.omit(myVec)`

```
myVec <- numeric (maxLength)  # a vector of maximum length

is.na(myVec) <- 1:maxLength   # set every item in myVec to NA

myVec[c(2,6,20)] <- 5         # add some values

na.omit(myVec)

#This will also work if you can initialize all of your values to something that you know you won't need.
```

Comment: @John: `myVec <- rep(NA, maxLength)` replaces your first two lines more cleanly.  Also, what's with the big writing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are more efficient ways.

It comes down to how you're using the data; your use case.  Are you taking out the data in in the same order you put it in, or in reversed order, or in random order, or in a sorted order?

For [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), for a fixed size array use a [circular buffer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ring/vignettes/ring.html), or for a fully dynamic size, use a [deque](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dequer/versions/2.0-1/topics/deque) (pronounced deck).  (This is probably what you want.)

For [FILO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)), use a [stack](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.0/topics/stack).

For grabbing the data at random, consider using a 1 column matrix you never resize.  Resizing is slow.

If you need an ordered set (eg `c(3,2,5) -> c(2,3,5)`), look into a [tree or a heap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datastructures/datastructures.pdf).

- A tree is good for comparisons, eg grabbing all elements in a set that is < 5.5.
- A heap is good for grabbing just the largest or smallest elements.