# Iteratively and efficiently adding elements to a list attribute of vertices in R igraph

Tags: performance, r, list, igraph

I'm working on a signal-propagation algorithm in **R**, using **igraph** (a library for random graphs) which involves working with a 2-level nested list.

Igraph allows to attach attributes to vertices (nodes of the graph), these can be vectors or lists, butin my application I need nested lists.

To see, try:

```
library("igraph")
g <- graph.full(10) # create a fully connected graph with 10 vertices
V(g)$letters <- list(NULL) # adds a list called "letters" to every vertex
V(g)$letters # results in a nested list
```

*I would like to add, in different stages, some pre-determined elements stored in a vector to a given subset of 2nd-level lists, where the subsetted list is the same size as the vector.*

The problem is to find an efficient way to add elements to the 2nd-level lists.

The simpler (and so far only) way to go is to write a loop:

```
set.seed(1234)

# every iteration represents a "round" of element addition ,
# followed by other operations. 
# So the attribute "letters" should not be populated in one sitting.
for (i in 1:10){

  # select randomly five 2nd-level lists (vertices) from the 1st-level list
  # the selected vertices are generated randomly for exposition, 
  # but I need to be able to select them from a well-defined vector (sel.ver)

  sel.vert <- sample(1:10, 5)

  # generate elements to add to the lists in the 2nd-level list (vertices)
  # again, i generate them randomly just to fill the vector, 
  #but the vector could be pre-determined

  add.elem <- sample(letters, 5)

  # now add add each element to its own list
  # notice that the first ELEMENT of add.elem (add.elem[1]) is added
  # to the attribute of the first SELECTED vertex (V(g)[sel.vert[1]]$letters,
  # the second element of add.elem with the second SELECTED vertex, and so on..

  for (l in 1:5){
    V(g)[sel.vert[l]]$letters <- list(c(V(g)[sel.vert[l]]$letters, add.elem[l]))    
  }
}
```

(I apologise to the experienced reader if this was a horror show of bad programming practices)

As the size of the initial network grows larger and more vertices are selected at every iteration (a random number, instead of 5), the loops become much slower. This should be a "workhorse" function, so I would like to speed it up.

I read the answer given to " [Efficiently adding or removing elements to a vector or list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778510/efficiently-adding-or-removing-elements-to-a-vector-or-list-in-r) " , namely, working with vectors whenever possible and preallocating their size, but I think it doesn't apply to my case, because:

1. I think that with **igraph** I have no choice but to use lists (at least at the first level)
2. at the second level, the lists will have different final lengths, depending on which vertices are randomly selected. So, it is difficult to preallocate a vector of the correct size. Even if I put very large vectors at the second level, initially filled with NAs (resulting in a list of vectors), I wouldn't know in which position to add elements (because the length of the list at any iteration is random), not to mention that I would need to remove NAs later.

This should be a particular case of adding elements (working with) nested list. As such,  I would think that maybe a faster implementation could be achieved by replacing the inner loop with `ddply` in *plyr* or `do.call`, but I couldn't manage to write the function to apply: `get the elements of the (inner) list and add this new element (itself a subset of a vector)`

Any comment or suggestion is appreciated. Hope the post is clear.

Comment: Do you need to perform some `igraph` operation on `g` on each iteration (i.e., do something other than populating `V(g)$letters`), or is it okay to populate all the `V(g)$letters` data first?

Comment: I would perform other operations between one round of additions and the other, so I cant't populate the nested lists in one sitting. 
The loop is a bit ambiguous, but I needed to illustrate that the vertices's attributes are populated layer by layer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# number of vertices to add elements to at a time
nv <- 5

# selected vertices and elements
sel.ver <- sample(V(g), nv)
add.elem <- sample(letters, nv)

V(g)$letters[sel.ver] <- lapply(1:nv, function(x) {
  c(add.elem[x], unlist(V(g)$letters[sel.ver[x]]))
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not quite what I was looking for. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, but I'm looking for a function that *adds* elements to the inner list, in *addition to the existing ones*. If I run your function twice, the content of the second iteration *replaces* the one of the first.
Anyways, the ddply statement is a good starting point.
Do you think I need to make the question clearer?

Comment: I think I follow, see my edit, you can just combine instead of assigning within the lapply.

Comment: yes, I noticed (and mentioned) that I could assign vectors, as opposed to lists, to the attributes. However, since the final number of letters will be different for every vertex (cf. my code in the question and related points), I think a list is the way to go, but I may be wronf.

Comment: great, it's very close to what I had in mind. Could I just ask you: if instead of selecting the vertices randomly I wanted to select them deterministically, how would I need to change the code?

Comment: The first argument to `lapply` is what's being iterated over. In this case its `1:length(V(g))`, or the indices of the vertices. You could change that into the vertices you want to select and remove the `runif` bit.

Comment: I see...

I'm trying to adapt it to a case where I can see what the selected vertices are, but it populates every list, not just the selected vertices:

`V(g)$letters <- list(NULL)`
`sel.ver <- sample(V(g), 5)`
`V(g)$letters <- lapply(sel.ver, function(x) {`
`c(sample(letters, 5), unlist(V(g)$letters[x]))})`
`
is there something I don't get about llply?

Comment: Since you are assigning a list of smaller length, it recycles the elements. You have to explicitly assign then with `V(g)$letters[sel.ver] <-` ...

Comment: ok, that's very useful. One last thing: as I explained in the edit, both the `sel.ver` and `add.elem` are deterministic (pre-existing) vectors, I generate them randomly for exposition. (my bad for the confusion caused.) 
So, I need the 1st element of `add.elem` to be added to the first *selected* vertex attribute, the second `add.elem` to the second selected and so on...
How do I subset `add.elem` in your function to do that?
`add.elem[sel.ver]` or `add.elem[x]` don't work, because they refer to the position of the *vertices*, not of the elements. 
(That's why I went for a loop initially)

Comment: You see? It's also a matching problem and, unfortunately, even with your efficient llply statement, I can't get the result I was hoping for.

Comment: See edit. More than that and you should consider another question.

Comment: That works as I hoped (and had described in the question, albeit badly). Thank you very much for the patience and incremental effort.
It's a very clean solution.