# compatea value in two vectors and assign the compared results into a new vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector to be append, and here is the code,which is pretty slow due to the nrow is big.

All I want to is to speed up. I have tried c() and append() and both seems not fast enough.
   And I checkd [Efficiently adding or removing elements to a vector or list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778510/efficiently-adding-or-removing-elements-to-a-vector-or-list-in-r)

Here is the code:

```
compare<-vector()

for (i in 1:nrow(domin)){

  for (j in 1:nrow(domin)){
      a=0
    if ((domin[i,]$GPA>domin[j,]$GPA) & (domin[i,]$SAT>domin[j,]$SAT)){
      a=1  
    }
    compare<-c(compare,a)
  }
  print(i)
}
```

I found it is hard to figure out the index for the compare if I use

```
   #compare<-rep(0,times=nrow(opt_predict)*nrow(opt_predict))
```

Comment: You should be generating a matrix with `outer`, I think.

Comment: I feel like there could be a better title, since this is about efficiency of comparisons (I think), not appending?

Answer (score 6):

The information you want would be better placed in a matrix:

```
v1 <- 1:3
v2 <- c(1,2,2)
mat1 <- outer(v1,v1,`>`)
mat2 <- outer(v2,v2,`>`)
both <- mat1 & mat2
```

To see which positions the inequality holds for, use `which`:

```
which(both,arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   3   1
```

Comments:

- This answer should be a lot faster than your loop. However, you are really just sorting two vectors, so there is probably a faster way to do this than taking the exhaustive set of inequalities...
- In your case, there is only a partial ordering (since, for a given `i` and `j`, it is possible that neither one is strictly greater than the other in both dimensions). If you were satisfied with sorting first on `v1` and then on `v2`, you could use the data.table package to easily get a full ordering:

  ```
  set.seed(1)
  v1 <- sample.int(10,replace=TRUE)
  v2 <- sample.int(10,replace=TRUE)

  require(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(v1,v2)
  setkey(DT)
  DT[,rank:=.GRP,by='v1,v2']
  ```

  which gives

  ```
      v1 v2 rank
   1:  1  8    1
   2:  3  3    2
   3:  3  8    3
   4:  4  2    4
   5:  6  7    5
   6:  7  4    6
   7:  7 10    7
   8:  9  5    8
   9: 10  4    9
  10: 10  8   10
  ```

  It depends on what you were planning to do next.

Comment: To clarify, v1 and v2 are your GPA and SAT vectors.