# Is there a way to vectorize these bootstrappign loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I'm new to R.  I'm used to VB where loops are used heavily, but I know R is much more efficient if I can vectorize the data.  I don't know if it's possible to vectorize what I've constructed here.

The general idea is, for `n=3:N`:

1. Pull a random sample (without replacement) of size `n` from the original sample (of size `N`)
2. Run a bootstrap parameter estimate on this subsample using `B` resamples
3. Do it again `X` times
4. Average all `X` parameter estimates and check convergence (i.e., look at the standard deviation between estimates or something like that - TBD).

I didn't implement step 4 yet, so the code below just does steps 1:3. Step 4 should be simple enough to do outside the loop using `rowMeans()`.

*Note: I set B and X to 100 for testing, but I need both to equal 10,000 (or more) for final use*

```
# simulate observation of N=30
bdf <- data.frame(sample(8:13, 30, rep = TRUE)

# get number of observations
N <- length(bdf)

# set number of bootstrap replicates
B <- 100

# set number of times to repeat the estimate
X <- 100

# create empty storage container for results
result_vec <- vector(length=B)

# this loop iterates over the number of times to repeat the estimate
for (j in 1:X) {
  
  # this loop iterates sample size from n=2 to n=N
  for (i in 3:N) {
    
    # random sample of size n
    boot_samp <- bdf[sample(N, size=i, replace=FALSE)]
    
    # this loop does the bootstrap sampling
    for(b in 1:B) {
      # draw a bootstrap sample
      bsamp <- sample(boot_samp, size=i, replace=TRUE)
      
      # calculate your parameter
      p <- mean(bsamp)
      #p <- sd(bsamp)
      
      # save the calculated parameter
      result_vec[b] <- p
      
    }
    if (i==3) {
      # initiate data frame and store the results for n=2 parameter estimate
      df_res <- data.frame(result_vec)
    }
    else {
      # add the results for n=i parameter estimate to the data frame
      df_temp <- data.frame(result_vec)
      df_res <- cbind(df_res, df_temp)
    }
    
    # rename the column in the data frame as n=i
    names(df_res)[ncol(df_res)] <- paste("n = ",i)
  }
  
  # calculate the mean of the parameter estimates
  allmeans <- colMeans(df_res)
  
  if (j==1) {
    # initiate a new data frame to store the means
    df_means <- data.frame(allmeans)
  }
  else {
    # add the results to the existing data frame
    df_temp <- data.frame(allmeans)
    df_means <- cbind(df_means, df_temp)
  }
  
  # rename the column in the data frame with j
  names(df_means)[ncol(df_means)] <- j
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, but I tried replacing the DIY bootstrapping loop with a `boot::boot` function call and it was WAY slower. For X=1 and B=10000, my original code took 59 seconds to run, while using the `boot` function took almost 3 minutes. Running on Posit Cloud, so not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest speed culprit here is repeatedly calling `cbind` to grow your `data.frame`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778510/efficiently-adding-or-removing-elements-to-a-vector-or-list-in-r?rq=3).

The loops can all be replaced with a couple `mapply` calls. Since the innermost loop is done with replacement, the samples can be done all at once and placed in a matrix for `rowMeans`.

```
# simulate observation of N=30
bdf <- data.frame(sample(8:13, 30, rep = TRUE))

# get number of observations
N <- nrow(bdf)

# set number of bootstrap replicates
B <- 1e4

# set number of times to repeat the estimate
X <- 100

# replace the loops to iterate over the number of times to repeat the estimate
system.time({
  df_means <- mapply(
    \(j) colMeans(
      mapply(
        \(i) rowMeans(matrix(sample(sample(bdf[,1], i), B*i, 1), B, i)), 3:N
      )
    ), 1:X
  )
  dimnames(df_means) <- list(paste0("n", 3:N), paste0("j", 1:X))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   21.58    1.39   22.98
```

Additionally, this procedure is really easy to run in parallel:

```
library(parallel)

X <- 1e3

system.time({
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # 15 cores
  clusterExport(cl, c("bdf", "N", "B"))
  df_means <- simplify2array(
    parLapply(cl, 1:X, \(j) colMeans(
      mapply(
        \(i) rowMeans(matrix(sample(sample(bdf[,1], i), B*i, 1), B, i)), 3:N
      )
    ))
  )
  
  stopCluster(cl)
  dimnames(df_means) <- list(paste0("n", 3:N), paste0("j", 1:X))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.02    0.14   22.08
```

Doing `B = X = 10000` in parallel would take less than 4 minutes on my aging laptop.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!  I was experimenting this am with trying to run the loops in parallel using `foreach`, but this is much cleaner. I will need to spend some time digging into the various `apply` functions to wrap my head around this, but thank you again.

Comment: In the first example, the outermost `mapply` could be replaced with `replicate(X,...` since `j` isn't used.

Comment: what does the `\(j)` argument do in the `parLapply()` call?  I read through the documentation on `lapply` and `parLapply` and some vignettes on each, but didn't see any examples like that.  I'm guessing it's a counter/index of some sort, but not sure I've seen that syntax before, so just curious.  Thanks again.

Comment: That's the function it is calling as it passes each of `1:X` as `j`. `\(j)` is shorthand for `function(j)`. Like I said, `j` isn't used in the function, so it's basically saying "run this function `X` times and store the results in a list".